# Assigning values to array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array structure. with the variable **$sortie**

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 480
        [1] => 483
        [2] => 497
        [3] => 481
        [4] => 478
        [5] => 475
        [6] => 476
        [7] => 477
        [8] => 498
        [9] => 496
        [10] => 502
        [11] => 499
        [12] => 494
        [13] => 503
        [14] => 493
        [15] => 500
        [16] => 484
        [17] => 501
        [18] => 495
        [19] => 485
        [20] => 489
        [21] => 490
        [22] => 488
        [23] => 487
        [24] => 486
    )
```

I'm trying to achieve something by assigning them on a new array using the following code.

```
        $release = array();
        foreach ($sortie as $key_true => $value_true) {
            $release[$key_true] = $value_true;
            echo $key_true.'---'.$value_true.'<br>';
        }
```

So far the echo results are going as expected with the correct order based on **$sortie**

however the **$release** array is not following the same ordering not assigning the **$key_true** to the **$release** array. Would appreciate any help why it's doing this.

**EDIT**
Sorry almost forgot, result of **$release** the values are the original key and original value

```
        Array
    (
        [0] => 0---480
        [1] => 1---483
        [2] => 10---502
        [3] => 11---499
        [4] => 12---494
        [5] => 13---503
        [6] => 14---493
        [7] => 15---500
        [8] => 16---484
        [9] => 17---501
        [10] => 18---495
        [11] => 19---485
        [12] => 2---497
        [13] => 20---489
        [14] => 21---490
        [15] => 22---488
        [16] => 23---487
        [17] => 24---486
        [18] => 3---481
        [19] => 4---478
        [20] => 5---475
        [21] => 6---476
        [22] => 7---477
        [23] => 8---498
        [24] => 9---496
    )
```

Comment: Can you post your `$release` array you getting ?

Comment: Is it just a coincidence that the $release values are the same as what you are outputting to screen?

Comment: What about `$release = $sortie;`?

Comment: @khany not the same. look at the $release values and check their key --- values.

Comment: Can you show us how you assigning values to `$sortie` ? Can make sure keys are integer and not string ?

Comment: @Rikesh `$q = 0; foreach ($valid_prod as $key => $value) {$sortie[$q]= $key;$q++;}` this is how I assigned sortie.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is change array to this structure:

```
$sortie = [480, 483, ...]; 
$release = [];
foreach($sortie as $val) {
  $release[$val] = true;
}
```

And then you can use php array [sorting functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting in  $release == array();, it may work around for you as far as assigning is concerned